# Single row per id to multiple row per id

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape, melt

I'd like to expand observations from single row-per-id to multiple rows-per-id based on a given time interval:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(123, 456, 789), gender = c(0, 1, 1), yr.start = c(2005, 
2010, 2000), yr.last = c(2007, 2012, 2000)), .Names = c("id", 
"gender", "yr.start", "yr.last"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id gender yr.start yr.last
  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1   123      0     2005    2007
2   456      1     2010    2012
3   789      1     2000    2000
```

I want to get id expanded into one row per year:

```
> dput(df_out)
structure(list(id = c(123, 123, 123, 456, 456, 456, 789), gender = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), yr = c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2000)), .Names = c("id", "gender", "yr"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
> df_out
# A tibble: 7 x 3
     id gender    yr
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1   123      0  2005
2   123      0  2006
3   123      0  2007
4   456      1  2010
5   456      1  2011
6   456      1  2012
7   789      1  2000
```

I know how to melt/reshape, but I'm not sure how I can expand the years.
Thanks.

Comment: How many columns does your production data set have? Just 3 like here or many more?

Comment: Non varying columns (like gender in the example above), between 2 and 10. But this is not an issue, as I can do a join later. Otherwise, I only have a time interval. In reality, I have dates, not year, and though I have extracted the year I may want to be more precise by expanding into days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a base R method.

```
# expand years to a list
yearList <- mapply(":", df$yr.start, df$yr.last)
```

Now, use this list to calculate the number of rows to repeat for each ID (the second argument of `rep`) and then append it as a vector (transformed from list with `unlist`) using `cbind`.

```
# get data.frame
cbind(df[rep(seq_along(df$id), lengths(yearList)), c("id", "gender")], yr=unlist(yearList))
     id gender   yr
1   123      0 2005
1.1 123      0 2006
1.2 123      0 2007
2   456      1 2010
2.1 456      1 2011
2.2 456      1 2012
3   789      1 2000
```

Answer (score 4):

You could `gather` into long format and then fill in the missing rows via `complete` using *tidyr*.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
     gather(group, yr, starts_with("yr") ) %>%
     group_by(id, gender) %>%
     complete(yr = full_seq(yr, period = 1) )
```

You can use `select` to get rid of the extra column.

```
df %>%
     gather(group, yr, starts_with("yr") ) %>%
     select(-group) %>%
     group_by(id, gender) %>%
     complete(yr = full_seq(yr, period = 1) )

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id, gender [3]
     id gender    yr
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1   123      0  2005
2   123      0  2006
3   123      0  2007
4   456      1  2010
5   456      1  2011
6   456      1  2012
7   789      1  2000
8   789      1  2000
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(id, gender) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ seq(.x$yr.start, .x$yr.last))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  rename(year = data)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
     id gender  year
  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1   123      0  2005
2   123      0  2006
3   123      0  2007
4   456      1  2010
5   456      1  2011
6   456      1  2012
7   789      1  2000
```

Comment: Thanks. I was benchmarking against the base R solution from @lmo, and this seems a lot slower (I have >1M rows)

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel Yeah, the nesting and unnest step is very slow if your data is large.

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel I will stick with the base R solution here since your data is kind of large

Answer (score 3):

As the OP mentions that his production data set has more than 1 M rows and he is benchmarking the different solutions, it might be worthwhile to try a `data.table` version:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
data.table(DF)[, .(yr = yr.start:yr.last), by = .(id, gender)]
```

which returns

> ```
>     id gender    yr
> 1: 123      0  2005
> 2: 123      0  2006
> 3: 123      0  2007
> 4: 456      1  2010
> 5: 456      1  2011
> 6: 456      1  2012
> 7: 789      1  2000
> ```

---

If there are more non-varying columns than just `gender` it might be more efficient to do a join rather than including all those columns in the grouping parameter `by =`:

```
data.table(DF)[DF[, .(yr = yr.start:yr.last), by = id], on = "id"]
```

> ```
>     id gender yr.start yr.last    yr
> 1: 123      0     2005    2007  2005
> 2: 123      0     2005    2007  2006
> 3: 123      0     2005    2007  2007
> 4: 456      1     2010    2012  2010
> 5: 456      1     2010    2012  2011
> 6: 456      1     2010    2012  2012
> 7: 789      1     2000    2000  2000
> ```

Note that both approaches assume that `id` is unique in the input data.

---

### Benchmarking

The OP has [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661988/single-row-per-id-to-multiple-row-per-id/44664086#comment76341178_44664086) that he is surprised that above `data.table` solution is five times slower than [lmo's base R solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44662370/3817004), apparently with OP's production data set of more than 1 M rows.

Also, the question has attracted 5 different answers plus additional suggestions. So, it's worthwhile to compare the solution in terms of processing speed.

#### Data

As the production data set isn't available, and problem size among other factors like the strcuture of the data is important for benchmarking, sample data sets are created.

```
# parameters
n_rows <- 1E2
yr_range <- 10L
start_yr <- seq(2000L, length.out = 10L, by = 1L)
# create sample data set
set.seed(123L)
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id = seq_len(n_rows),
                 gender = sample(0:1, n_rows, replace = TRUE),
                 yr.start = sample(start_yr, n_rows, replace = TRUE))
DT[, yr.last := yr.start + sample(0:yr_range, n_rows, replace = TRUE)]
DF <- as.data.frame(DT)
str(DT)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  4 variables:
>  $ id      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
>  $ gender  : int  0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 ...
>  $ yr.start: int  2005 2003 2004 2009 2004 2008 2009 2006 2004 2001 ...
>  $ yr.last : int  2007 2013 2010 2014 2008 2017 2013 2009 2005 2002 ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

For the first run, 100 rows are created, the start year can vary between 2000 and 2009, and the span of years an indivdual `id` can cover is between 0 and 10 years. Thus, the result set should be expected to have approximately 100 * (10 + 1) / 2 rows.

Also, only one additional column `gender` is included although [the OP has told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661988/single-row-per-id-to-multiple-row-per-id/44664086#comment76314112_44661988) that the producion data may have 2 to 10 non-varying columns.

#### Code

```
library(magrittr)
bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  lmo = {
    yearList <- mapply(":", DF$yr.start, DF$yr.last)
    res_lmo <- cbind(DF[rep(seq_along(DF$id), lengths(yearList)), c("id", "gender")], 
                     yr=unlist(yearList))
  },
  hao = {
    res_hao <- DF %>%
      dplyr::group_by(id, gender) %>%
      tidyr::nest() %>%
      dplyr::mutate(data = purrr::map(data, ~ seq(.x$yr.start, .x$yr.last))) %>%
      tidyr::unnest() %>%
      dplyr::rename(yr = data)
  },
  aosmith = {
    res_aosmith <- DF %>%
      tidyr::gather(group, yr, dplyr::starts_with("yr") ) %>%
      dplyr::select(-group) %>%
      dplyr::group_by(id, gender) %>%
      tidyr::complete(yr = tidyr::full_seq(yr, period = 1) )
  },
  jason = {
    res_jason <- DF %>%
      dplyr::group_by(id, gender) %>%
      dplyr::do(data.frame(yr=.$yr.start:.$yr.last))
  },
  uwe1 = {
    res_uwe1 <- DT[, .(yr = yr.start:yr.last), by = .(id, gender)]
  },
  uwe2 = {
    res_uwe2 <- DT[DT[, .(yr = yr.start:yr.last), by = id], on = "id"
                   ][, c("yr.start", "yr.last") := NULL]
  },
  frank1 = {
    res_frank1 <- DT[rep(1:.N, yr.last - yr.start + 1L), 
                     .(id, gender, yr = DT[, unlist(mapply(":", yr.start, yr.last))])]
    },
  frank2 = {
    res_frank2 <- DT[, {
      m = mapply(":", yr.start, yr.last); c(.SD[rep(.I, lengths(m))], .(yr = unlist(m)))}, 
      .SDcols=id:gender]
  },
  times = 3L
)
```

Note that references to *tidyverse* functions are explicit in order to avoid name conflicts due to a cluttered name space.

#### First run

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>     expr        min          lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
>      lmo    655.860    692.6740    968.749    729.488   1125.193   1520.899     3
>      hao  40610.776  41484.1220  41950.184  42357.468  42619.887  42882.307     3
>  aosmith 319715.984 336006.9255 371176.437 352297.867 396906.664 441515.461     3
>    jason  77525.784  78197.8795  78697.798  78869.975  79283.804  79697.634     3
>     uwe1    834.079    870.1375    894.869    906.196    925.264    944.332     3
>     uwe2   1796.910   1810.8810   1880.482   1824.852   1922.268   2019.684     3
>   frank1    981.712   1057.4170   1086.680   1133.122   1139.164   1145.205     3
>   frank2    994.172   1003.6115   1081.016   1013.051   1124.438   1235.825     3
> ```

For the given problem size of 100 rows, the timings clearly indicate that the `dplyr`/ `tidyr` solutions are magnitudes slower than base R or `data.table`  solutions.

The results are essentially consistent:

```
all.equal(as.data.table(res_lmo), res_uwe1)
all.equal(res_hao, res_uwe1)
all.equal(res_jason, res_uwe1)
all.equal(res_uwe2, res_uwe1)
all.equal(res_frank1, res_uwe1)
all.equal(res_frank2, res_uwe1)
```

return `TRUE` except `all.equal(res_aosmith, res_uwe1)` which returns

> `[1] "Incompatible type for column yr: x numeric, y integer"`

#### Second run

Due to the long execution times, the `tidyverse` solutions are skipped when benchmarking larger problem sizes.

With the modified parameters

```
n_rows <- 1E4
yr_range <- 100L
```

the result set is expected to consist of about 500'000 rows.

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    lmo 425.026101 447.716671 455.85324 470.40724 471.26681 472.12637     3
   uwe1   9.555455   9.796163  10.05562  10.03687  10.30571  10.57455     3
   uwe2  18.711805  18.992726  19.40454  19.27365  19.75091  20.22817     3
 frank1  22.639031  23.129131  23.58424  23.61923  24.05685  24.49447     3
 frank2  13.989016  14.124945  14.47987  14.26088  14.72530  15.18973     3
```

For the given problem size and structure the `data.table` solutions are the fastest while the base R approach is a magnitude slower. The most concise solution `uwe1` is also the fastest, here.

Note that the results depend on the structure of the data, in particular the parameters `n_rows` and `yr_range` and the number of non-varying columns. If there are more of those columns than just `gender` the timings might look differently.

The benchmark results are in contradiction to the OP's observation on execution speed which needs to be further investigated.

Comment: Thanks for the `data.table` solution.  I'm a bit surprised at its performance.
`data.table
user  system elapsed 
38.14    0.00   38.25`

vs. base R (see above):
`user  system elapsed 
8.54    0.05    8.62`

Comment: I'm surprised as well. @Frank, do you have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: The benchmark results don't confirm your observation. So, there must be additional differences in the  structure of your data and/or code which make your production data distinct. Also, Frank suggested better to use  `DT = data.table(DF)` instead of `setDT(DF)`.

Comment: Thanks for the through simulation.  I will have to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `do` in `dplyr`, but it's slower than the base R method.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, gender) %>%
  do(data.frame(yr=.$yr.start:.$yr.last))

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# # Groups:   id, gender [3]
#      id gender    yr
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
# 1   123      0  2005
# 2   123      0  2006
# 3   123      0  2007
# 4   456      1  2010
# 5   456      1  2011
# 6   456      1  2012
# 7   789      1  2000
```

Comment: Thanks. I explored some of the dplyr approaches. As you point out, they tend to be slower than alternative approaches.  Because my dataset is large, I need to give consideration to computational efficiency. Otherwise, for consistency with my code, I would have picked a tidyverse approach.